# Delayed Progress/Activity Indication

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

For the time being a use the code below to activate some ongoing actions indication for the user (wonna download some files ... if it takes longer than one second I display the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `UIProgressView. The problem is that for some reason it works on iPhone but not stable on iPad. Especially when the time is near the limit.

```
        __block BOOL hasDownloads = YES;
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            if (hasDownloads) {
                [weakSelf progressInformationShow:YES];
            }
        });
```

After that code I start file downloading in a background thread with a completion handler. The completion handler checks the remaining file downloads and sets the hasDownloads flag to NO when the last download is complete.

Is there a better solution for that or whats wrong with the code?

EDIT
The progress nor the completion block got called on the pad but on the phone?!

Comment: Make sure you read and set `hasDownloads` only at the main thread, this way you should rid of race between set/read the value.

Comment: Is set in the main thread. It seems that my completion handler is not called on the iPad. Don't know why.